# Isnt any solution to move the 3d cursor and origin to pivot?

Tags: 3d-cursor

I want to place the 3d cursor at the particular place but i just able to place the pivot at that point, i have no idea how to move the 3d cursor and origin to the point. Seek for help

Answer (score 1):

You can position the 3D cursor by hitting or holding Shift and right mouse button in the 3D view, the 3d cursor coordinates are located on the view side panel of the 3D veiw and hitting shift + S will bring up a menu with other 3D cursor options. If you want to make an objects origin point the 3D cursors position just right mouse click in 3D view and go to "Set Origin" also Shift + C will reposition the 3D cursor back to the worlds center.